# How retry works in Azure Service Bus Java

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm new to service bus, I'm curious about RetryPolicy and how it works, as per the documentation, retry had happened automatically for transient exceptions(MessagingExcepitons, ServerBusy), and the default retry count is 3, but we can set out custom retry policy using RetryExponential class.

I want to see the logs does the RetryPolicy did actually trying  to connect or not when exception occurs.

How can I check this, how to replicate MessagingExcepitons, ServerBusy exceptions, so that I can see the logs. I'm using azure service bus java sdk.

Can any one help me to understand this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Java SDK is open source and looking for `retryPolicy` in these files shows how the underlying implementation uses it

- [CoreMessageSender](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/f3ca0209d44fb3498fb184047f4fd5bcbe5a3c41/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/primitives/CoreMessageSender.java)
- [CoreMessageReceiver](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/f3ca0209d44fb3498fb184047f4fd5bcbe5a3c41/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/primitives/CoreMessageReceiver.java)

For example, here's the flow for `CoreMessageSender` when an error is thrown

1. When an error occurs and if its a ServiceBusException, a retry is scheduled - [See line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/primitives/CoreMessageSender.java#L527)
2. After waiting, it ensures the link is still open and increments the retry count - [See line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/primitives/CoreMessageSender.java#L782)
3. This continues and on successful completion it resets the count - [See line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/primitives/CoreMessageSender.java#L564)

As for logging, the Java SDK uses [SLF4J](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/pom.xml#L74) and you can see the required logs with a line like this in your code

```java
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

Logger.getLogger("com.microsoft.azure.servicebus").setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

Comment: Thanks Pramod, can I explicitly  throw ServiceBusException from my client code to see this.

Comment: AFAIK your client exception won't trigger this retry policy. Only exceptions thrown from the underlying transport layer would trigger this. You could probably try simulating network problems to trigger this functionality. If you are running containers, you could try using something like [pumba](https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba)